# X and Y axis off

Tags: modeling

I create an object, from other object face. When moving it, I noticed that the movement is not correct on X and Y. I turned on axis, and I see that they are completely off. How did that happened and how can it be fixed?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose the object has been rotated in edit mode.

A possibility to fix it is to use a new feature in 2.8: manipulating the object origin only.

To enable this option, use:

[image]

Then to fix the axis alignment, set snapping on to edge for move and rotate:

[image]

So you can move and rotate the axis to realign it to your mesh:

[image]

You can now desactivate the option that afects only the origin.

And use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to realign the entire object to the global axis.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for "local" orientations, instead of global.

If this does not resolve the problem, probably you have rotated the vertices in edit mode, so you have to create your own custom coordinate system: in edit mode select a face, then press the plus icon near the list of the transform orientations. Give it a name and use it for your transforms.

[image]

Comment: I did that, it does not change, stays the same.

Comment: I updated my answer.